# How can I allow thread 2 to communicate on the port I opened in thread 1?

Tags: c++, multithreading, serial-port, thread-synchronization

I'm trying to communicate with the same port using two different threads in a CLI C++ program (running on Windows but not using the Windows API). The port is a USB port (that leads to a converter to RS-232 and then to another device). I can successfully establish port communications in my `main` thread using `OpenCom()` and `Transmit()`, functions provided in a DLL by the manufacturer of those devices.

I then call `newThreadFunc()` (defined in another DLL), which runs in a separate thread (let's call it the *callback thread*) and calls a callback function. In that callback function, I call `Transmit()` again, but now it returns with an error (defined by the DLL): "Port not ready (CreateFile)".

Here is the simplified pseudo-code:

```
#include "Device.h"            // contains OpenCom() & Transmit()

const short comPort = 3; // COM port number (global)

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    OpenCom(comPort);          // Open the port
    Transmit(command);         // where "command" represents some command

    newThreadFunc(taskHandle); // Creates new "callback thread" and calls callbackFunc
    getchar();                 // wait while other thread runs
    return 0;
}

signed long __cdecl callbackFunc (params) {
    Transmit(command);         // error: "Port not ready (CreateFile)"
    OpenCom(comPort);          // error: "Port already open (CreateFile)"
}
```

If I call `OpenCom` in the callback thread, I get this error: "Port already open (CreateFile)". So the callback thread can see that the port is open but cannot communicate on it. I know I should manage the port communications somehow with a mutex or similar, but what's the reason why the callback thread can't communicate on the port? And how can I allow the callback thread to communicate on the port I opened in the main thread?

Answer (score 4):

Serial ports are *very* simple devices, they just support an opaque stream of bytes.  There is no protocol to allow two threads or two applications to share a port.  Nothing like TCP that allows a logical connection to a specific port number across a single network connection.  In the [OSI model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), a serial port occupies the bottom one, the physical layer.  With no standard that ever emerged to build layers on top of it, nobody ever agreed on what layer #2 should look like.  The Hayes AT protocol for modems is as far as it ever got.

So if the OS would actually allow you do this then the outcome would be very poor.  One app or thread would steal the input meant for another, that can never come to a good end.  So you really *do* have to take care of this yourself and open the port once.  With some kind of scheme to arbitrate access to the port that determines which thread gets the input.  Like a mutex.  Or a network layer you create that has a logical destination address, very common in bus protocols.  That can be as simple as a single byte in a message.  But of course adding the requirement that you implement the data link layer and specify a message frame format so this byte can reliably be read.  Very common as well, everybody spins their own.

Comment: Did I understand correctly? If I open a port in thread 1, there is no way to communicate with it in thread 2 without first closing it in thread 1? Or do you mean this should be possible with a mutex?

Comment: The port can only be opened once, hard requirement.  Hopefully you understand by now why this requirement exists.  If you want to use a mutex to ensure that only *one* thread can ever read data from the port then, yes, that could work.

Comment: I see. And I can't communicate with a port unless *that thread* has opened it (rather than another thread)?

Comment: I don't understand the hang-up.  Trying again: somebody has to open the port, it doesn't matter who does it.  You typically prefer your main() function to do that.  Which gets you a HANDLE, any thread can call ReadFile() with that handle.  Just like any thread can use a handle to a file.  No *two* threads should ever call ReadFile() at the same time, it is completely unpredictable which one wins.

Comment: Ok, that helps a lot. In my case, since I use functions in a DLL (which I can't read) to communicate with the port, I never see the handle and let the DLL take care of it. Perhaps the reason I can't communicate with the port using the callback thread is something inherent to that DLL rather than my code. The code should work even without a mutex because I use the blocking function getchar(), so I know the main thread isn't trying to use the port. (There's a long delay between calling `newThreadFunc()` and `callbackFunc()`, so I'm sure the first call to `Transmit()` has finished by then.)